# Motion of gears

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-kinematics

By placing several double-reduction gears in a chain, it is possible to create a system where the final (larger) gear will make more rotations than the first (smaller) gear. From what I understand of mechanics, this is not supposed to be possible.

What's going on?

Comment: Can you point specifically to what mechanics principle or effect that is supposed to make this not possible?

Comment: Is there a limitation that all gear operate on the same plane, or can there be two or more gears on the same axle?

Comment: Each double-red gear consists of 1 small & 1 large gear sharing an axle. String them together out to near-infinity and one rotation of first gear will create near-infinite rotations of final gear. Only thing that must be overcome is resting state of the gears, which is a finite amount of force. This can also be overcome by stringing a standard gear system in the opposite direction to create torque necessary to turn first/middle gear. 

How has this not been tried?

Comment: @Newton'sNuts - better to [edit] the question with all relevant details instead of adding information in the comments.

Answer (score 2):

If no gears share an axle, and they are all rotating on the same plane, then each gear pair shares tangential velocity where the gears contact.

[image: fig1]

When each pair shares tangential velocity, it means that all contacts have the same tangential velocity in measure. The direction flips, but the speed is the same.

So now reduce the system into just the input and output gears and their rotation equals to the tangential velocity $v$ divided by each radius

$$ \begin{aligned}
 \omega_0 & = \frac{v}{R_0} & \omega_6 & = \frac{v}{R_6}
\end{aligned} $$

This means that the only thing important is the ratio of radii $R_0/R_6$ that determines the ratio of rotation $\omega_6/\omega_0$

Comment: Gears share axles.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing in mechanics that prevents the final large gear from rotating faster than the initial small gear. It does not violate any conservation law nor any of Newton’s laws.

In particular you may incorrectly believe that this arrangement violates the conservation of energy, that more energy must be coming out of the fast gear than was put into the slow gear. This is not the case. The rate of energy is the torque times the angular velocity. The fast end will have a high angular velocity, but the torque will be low. All in all, the energy will thus be conserved.

Comment: Using this arrangement with the final gear turning the armature of a generator, I could power the world while pedaling my bike. Call it what you want, but that doesn't sound like Conservation of Energy.

Comment: Nonsense- see my answer.

Comment: @NewtonsNuts said “with the final gear turning the armature of a generator, I could power the world while pedaling my bike” that is incorrect. Changing the gearing ratio doesn’t change your power. In the extreme you mention even the slightest load would result in a force that would exceed your leg muscles

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you had a train of reduction gears each of which doubled the speed of rotation of the next. With sixteen gears, the farthest would in principle turn  about a million times faster than the first. However, the turning force of the furthest would be a million times less than that of the first. Were you to build such a device (you can see examples on youtube) you would quickly reach the point at which the turning force required to make the first cog move at any appreciable speed is far too high for a human to generate it by hand. If you try to make it work by brute force on the first cog, you will at some point encounter a mechanical failure of one of the components.

Here is an example of such a train being operated in reverse- as a reduction gear. An electric motor at one end causes a cog at the other end to turn once every 13 billion years.  https://www.reddit.com/r/interestingasfuck/comments/6kk3tl/the_final_gear_in_this_gear_train_will_take_137/